# Ionic3 - this.NavCtrl.push() is not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, navigation, buttonclick

I am trying to navigate to another page on click of button.

There are two pages home & base in home.html.
    `<button ion-button click="onclick()"> Go</button>`

In `home.ts` I have imported `BasePage` module.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BasePage } from '../base/base';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }
onclick(){
  this.navCtrl.push(BasePage)
}
}
```

In `app.module.ts` I have imported the same `BasePage`

It is not redirecting to the page. Neither there is any error on console. I have checked out many sites. They have used the same function that works correctly. 
I am using angular3.

Comment: is BasePage lazy loaded? and you have a typo `this.NavCtrl.push` it needs to be `this.navCtrl.push`

Comment: @SurajRao no for that reason only i created a fresh app. and checked. Still there is some problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your button code doesn't look correct respectively the `click` isn't well formatted and therefore won't be correctly handled, I guess.

Instead of

```
<button ion-button click="onclick()"> Go</button>
```

Try **(click)**

```
<button ion-button (click)="onclick()"> Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to trigger a function when something happen you have to use events. In templates the events go in brackets. That is what David Dal is fixing in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your template file it should be-

```
<button ion-button (click)="onclick()"> Go</button>
```

In Your Component file You missed semi-colon. Termination is best practice for any programming language.

```
onclick(){
    this.navCtrl.push(basePage);
}
```

And last thing is kindly import BasePage in your app.module.ts file

Answer (score -1):

It would be better to define a class property that contains the page reference.
Try to do something like this in your .ts file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BasePage } from '../base/base';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  basePage: BasePage = BasePage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  onclick(){
    this.navCtrl.push(this.basePage);
  }
}
```

In this way you have the page reference into a property. Use that property as a "navigator".

By the way try to do this in HTML:

```
<button ion-button (click)="onclick()">Some Button</button>
```

Also be sure to have add your BasePage to App Module file or it won't work!

Hope to be helpful ;)

> Note that you could use [navPush] directive directly in your HTML button instead of making a function (if the result you want to achieve is simple navigation). In this case just create the property as I show and in your HTML make this < button ion-button [navPush]="basePage" >Button Name< /button> it will work without using any function!